# os.mknod() fails on MacOS?

Tags: python

Is `os.mknod()` a privileged call on Mac? It always fails with operation not permitted?

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.mknod("/tmp/test123")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1b8032a076af> in <module>()
----> 1 os.mknod("/tmp/test123")

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the OSX manpage https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mknod.2.html

```
Mknod() requires super-user privileges.
```

Works except from the invalid argument

```
sudo python -c "import os; os.mknod('/tmp/test123')"
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately `mknod` requires escalated privileges. If you don't need `mknod` specifically though, just create the file with `open`, which doesn't require escalation:

```
open('/tmp/test123', 'w').close()
```

If you want to write to the file in addition to creating it:

```
with open('/tmp/test123', 'w') as file:
    file.write('hello world')
```

Using `with` as above will automatically close the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `os.makedirs` solve the problem.